# when we apply formatter function on field then search functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Will search filter work when we apply formatter on that particular field? For example:

XML code :

```
<Text id="id" text="{parts :['key>para1','key>para2','key>para3'],
   formatter: '.formatter.someStatus'}"></Text>
```

Controller code :

```
onSearch: function(oEvent) {
  var sQuery = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
  var oList = this.getView().byId("tableid");
  var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
  if (sQuery) {
    var aFilter = [];
    aFilter.push(new Filter("para1", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
    aFilter.push(new Filter("para2", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
    aFilter.push(new Filter("para3", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
    oBinding.filter(new Filter({
      filters: aFilter,
      and: false
    }));
  } else {} // Use empty filter to show all list items // oBinding.filter(new Filter([])); does not work oBinding.filter([]);
}
```

Formatter code:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"], function(JSONModel) {
  return {
    someStatus: function(a, b, C) {
      if (a === "Y") {
        return "Approve";
      } else if (a === "N") {
        return C;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    }
  };
});
```

where a gives Y & N and C gives "Reject: some reason". It gives correct status result but upon search it is not returning right data. Please let me know in case of any further details required.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, by using a formatter function the binding is one-way. That means that if the value is 'Y' it gets shown as 'Approve' through your formatter, but `var sQuery = oEvent.getSource().getValue();` will return 'Y' and **not** 'Approve'.

Comment: That means, there is no way to achieve what I am trying here. Please suggest.

Comment: You cound do the same thing as in the formatter. `var sQuery = ""; var sValue = oEvent.getSource().getValue(); if (sValue === "Y") {
        sQuery = "Approve";
      } else if (sValue === "N") {
        sQuery = "reject:" + reason;
      }

Comment: Thanks Lumpenstein for your reply. Where I have write this condition in search or Formatter?

Comment: Inside you onSearch function.

Comment: I did in this way as few more columns are also there but it didn't work for single column also.Let me know if you need any further details required.

Comment: onSearch: function(oEvent) {
   var that = this;
   var sQuery = "";
var sValue = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
if (sValue === "Y") {
    sQuery = "Approve";
} else if (sValue === "N") {
    sQuery = "Reject";
}
var oList = this.getView().byId("idTable");
var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
if (sValue) {
    var aFilter = [];
aFilter.push(new Filter("para1", FilterOperator.Contains, sValue));aFilter.push(new Filter("para2", FilterOperator.Contains, sValue));  oBinding.filter(new Filter({
     filters: aFilter,
     and: false
    }));

Comment: Please provide an example using something like http://embed.plnkr.co/F2hZTBtSMNDKkNW0MrU6

Comment: You can refer below git hub link to access the app. Main focus on status column. This is one example. https://github.com/rkmishra2703/RK-/blob/master/formatterExample.zip

Comment: Any one has any suggestion pls ?